# Transistor characteristics in a file

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I'm creating a simple circuit simulator application. Is there somewhere a csv/xml/... database of diode and transistor characteristics?
It would be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give more detail about the format in which you are expecting the characteristics to be in ? Just a list of parameter values which can be plugged into standard device models ?

Comment: Sorry, but questions seeking help in finding off-site resources are categorically off topic here.  SE sites are reserved only for questions which can be answered with concise technical content posted *right here*.  This obviously excludes many things of interest, but the idea of SE is to handle a particular type of question well, and leave all the other sorts to the remainder of the Internet.

Comment: AJN: yes, like a csv file with Ice0, current-amplification, maximal voltages...

Comment: What sort of simulation features did you have in mind that Falstad’s cannot do?

Comment: Well, it would simulate guitar amplifiers (for homemade ones).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but simple only gives you fixed hFE, and Beta for FETs=1/Ron, Vt

[image]
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+10.20027730826997+43+10+42%0At+256+192+320+192+0+1+-5.359823405427049+0.6373031999375245+100%0At+256+288+320+288+0+-1+13.3655701946979+-0.6373031999375263+100%0Aw+320+208+320+240+0%0Aw+320+240+320+272+0%0Aw+320+304+320+352+0%0Ar+256+288+256+352+0+220%0Ar+256+192+256+128+0+220%0Ad+256+240+256+288+2+default%0AR+256+240+192+240+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+256+352+320+352+0%0Aw+256+128+320+128+0%0Aw+320+128+320+176+0%0AR+256+128+256+80+0+0+40+10+0+0+0.5%0AR+256+352+256+400+0+0+40+-10+0+0+0.5%0Ad+256+192+256+240+2+default%0Aw+320+240+400+240+0%0Ar+400+240+432+240+0+1%0Ag+400+352+400+384+0%0AO+448+160+496+160+0%0Ao+8+64+0+4098+6+0.025+0+2+8+3%0Ao+18+64+0+4098+0.000091552734375+0.00009765625+1+1%0A

- tons of built in cct. From menu and right mouse, thumbwheel options with rubber band drawing of part corners or draw parts with touchpad or mouse...space bar for editing. Small pitch option otherwise invisible grid. Great for rapid demos. But no parts with ESR, DCR incl inverters , all 0 ohms so add for accuracy.

Vbe and diodes are very accurate up to 1mA then bulk resistance varies widely ESR~<1/Pmax power rating and ESR if dielectric/electrode interface but no variable hFE... anyways a good design depends on R ratios with worst case hFE.  Slew rate options on logic etc. Schmitt trigger threshold and Vcc options

You have to figure out how to convert to a text file format...see file> save text < import text or > link format shown above using JavaScript.

- libraries are open source. why re-invent the wheel? wish I had this in 1975